# 10 year old, extreme fear of vomiting (emetophobia)

Tags: anxiety, vomiting

My daughter is increasingly struggling with a fear of vomiting (emetophobia).  It started about 3-4 years ago when she vomited for the first time.  After that night, she struggled with anxiety around being afraid she was going to throw up, and as time passed it subsided.

Then about 2 years ago while visiting her grandparents (she was there with my wife) she vomited in the evening after having too much junk food.  Again, for a period after this she began becoming anxious shortly before going to bed being afraid that she would again vomit.  Again, as time passed it got better.

Recently (in the last year or so) she's steadily been becoming more anxious about this.  The pattern we're seeing that's getting more common is she'll be fine in the hours leading up to bedtime, but right before going to bed starts to become anxious, and worried that she'll throw up.  Early on we took more of an "oh sweetie, you're not going to throw up" (ie being dismissive) approach, but as time has gone on we're trying more to hear her concerns and reassure her that she's been through it before, that we're there to support her, etc.  Ie trying to validate her feelings, and assure her that it's normal and common to feel the way she does.

However, in the last month or two, it's been getting increasingly bad, her diet is now changing (she's refusing to eat sugary foods for fear of triggering vomit), starting to eat more bland foods, and tonight after dinner was already starting to get anxious (in spite of the fact she had a plain dinner of hot dog & simple salad, which are all things she eats often).

Things we've tried: breathing exercises, fidget toys, validating her feelings, assuring her she's been through the anxiousness before and has overcome it, pacing around the house when the anxiety gets bad, dedicated "talk times" where either myself or my wife have dedicated time to let her talk through her anxiety with us.  All of these have helped to varying degrees, but in spite of them all we still find things getting worse.

My wife & I are really struggling with how to support her.  We don't want to dismiss the anxiousness she's feeling, but at the same time it's clear this is escalating and getting worse.  We talked to our MD a couple months ago and didn't get much advice past "it's totally normal and common".  We feel like we need help, but aren't sure where to go for that?  Are there books we should read?  Should we seek out professional (ie counselling, etc) help?  What do we look for when seeking that out?  Googling finds a lot of generic advice that we've tried and hasn't seemed to be effective.

Comment: Can she pinpoint exactly what the issue about vomiting is? Is it the purely physical sensation, the reaction of people around her about having to clean it up, her feeling of having no control over it, …?

Comment: "We talked to our MD a couple months ago and didn't get much advice past 'it's totally normal and common'." Your doctor is incorrect; there is fear of vomiting (normal enough to write off), and there are intrusive thoughts, rumination, and anxiety about it, which is something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry you got closed for being a too specific medical question. Does she actually vomit or near vomit often? She could have a minimal pyloric stenosis that predisposes her to vomiting, for example. Or is this more an anxiety issue that focuses on this one concern? Is the vomiting or the anxiety "the problem"?

Answer (score 2):

#### Take her to see a psychologist.

Random internet strangers aren't suited to diagnose your child's mental illnesses or provide medical advice on how to treat them. If you believe that your child has a serious mental condition (and a genuine phobia would count), then you should take them to see a psychologist who can diagnose any conditions that they might have and provide a treatment plan for them.